# Electron app load external URL on application close

Tags: javascript, electron

I am trying to load a log-out URL once the app close button is hit,

Something like the following. Problem is that I am receiving an error that the window is already closed and can't load. Any help achieve this will be appreciated.

```
app.on('ready', function () {
    // Create new window
    mainWindow = new BrowserWindow({webPreferences: {
        nodeIntegration: false        
      }});

    // Load php index into window
    mainWindow.setTitle('Test');
    mainWindow.loadURL('http://www.url.com/index.php');
    //mainWindow.webContents.openDevTools();
    mainWindow.setMenu(null);
    mainWindow.on('closed', () => {         
        mainWindow.loadURL('https://www.url.com/logout.php?logout=true');       
        mainWindow = null;
        app.quit();
    });
});
```

Comment: Doesn't make sense. It's like saying ...  *when I close my browser go to a different web site*. Perhaps all you need is to make an a ajax request?

Comment: Well, the idea is closing the browser window first, than trigger the URL to log out and that to close the app. Thought that with simple link visit will be easier than ajax request.  And with Ajax might face problems with cors cross domain.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm a little confused by what you're trying to do, but it sounds like you can just load the URL when the `close` event is triggered, cancel the event to prevent `closed` from firing, and then when the page has loaded, you could close again, but this time for real.

```
mainWindow.on('close', (e) => {
    mainWindow.webContents.on('did-finish-load', logOutPageLoaded);        
    mainWindow.loadURL('https://www.url.com/logout.php?logout=true');       
    e.preventDefault();
});

function logOutPageLoaded() {
    mainWindow.destroy();
}

mainWindow.on('closed', () => {              
    mainWindow = null;
    app.quit();
});
```

Comment: This is exactly what I needed!